# Graphics2D Drawing Performance

Tags: java, performance, graphics2d

I am trying some things out with manually drawing "things" with a Java `Graphics2D` object within a Swing component and as I reach about >2000 squares that I order the object to draw it gets really slow.

I have no clue whether or not this is "common". Are 2000 objects to render really "a lot"? Is the `Graphics2D` object just not very performant? Should I just stop where I am now and rather switch to JOGL before I try out more complex stuff and it is too late?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) caused a.m. issues with 2000 Objects, short, runnable and compilable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a Java Spirograph GUI that draws tens of thousands of line segments in 20 milliseconds or less.

[image]

Make sure you are doing your calculations elsewhere in your application.  Your drawing code should do one thing and one thing only: draw.

However, there is a practical limit to the speed of Graphics and Graphics2D.  This Spirograph took 172 milliseconds to draw over 250,000 line segments.

[image]

Comment: My plan is to redraw the whole area about 10 times every second while I calculate a lot in the logic behind the UI for about every object before I draw. The drawing algorithm just iterates on an entry-set of a map and takes every object it finds, seperates it in 25 tiles and draws each tile on the screen. Is the "fetching" of these objects (just from references) maybe a bit too much logic within the drawing algorithm?

Comment: @salbeira: Does each object have 25 tiles, or is your whole entry set 25 tiles?  If each object has 25 tiles, how many tiles overlap?  You could speed things up if you eliminate overlap.

Comment: None overlap. Its basically a chuncking system inspired by minecraft's chunks. I save a chunk in a map, retrieve it and draw it according to it's relative position by taking each object within the chunk and draw something according to what that object is. It's just some testing right now to see how well it works.